# Firebase with third custom JWT

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I have four Appengine Standard Application.

For authentication I will receive a JWT token of my customer (They have an oauth provider), I know that Firebase has some defaults providers Oauth like as Github, Google, Facebook and integration with Javascript API is verey easy. But I need to use of my customer.

Is there a possibility to have a new OAuth provider in Firebase console to easily integration my app with firebase [like this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes)?

For the backend I am thinking to use SDK to validate a token.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(idToken).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign in with unsupported OAuth providers, your need to use [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). Here is a full example on how to authenticate with Instragram: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html